# How to text-align:center an absolute element on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the code:

html:

```
<div class=container1>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative !important;
  width: 260px !important;
}

.container2 {
  background: blue;
  border: solid 1px;
  float: left !important;
  height: 180px;
  /*position: relative; can't use, as it would limit icons inside this container*/
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  }
.container2:hover .box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    border: solid 1px;
    display: none;
    height: 120px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20px;

    width: 180px !important;
}

.box:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.icon {
  border: solid 1px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/388ygc74/10/

And on IE (any version) the text-align:center does not work.

The solution to make `.box` width:100% is not applicable, I need it to be a fixed defined width.

Any idea?

Comment: I got an "Error on page" error after going to the referenced jsfiddle.net link with IE8.Chrome did not generate this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `left: 30px;` (since you set the `width` to `60px`) playing with `z-index` and `position: relative` ?

(Yes, you said no `position:relative;` but it's working :) )

[See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/388ygc74/12/)

Comment: It works, but `.container2` will have variable width, not always 60px... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you looking for?

```
left:50%
margin-left:{-50% of elementh width}px;
```

Add specific selector to add the element that you want to align

```
:nth-child(4)
```